# The Filter geometry function in T-SQL is not precise and does not return valid results

Tags: sql-server, graph, geometry

I have two tables, [edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTJpR.jpg) (a set of polyline features) and [nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELOMS.jpg) (set of points)

I want to find the "**id**" of those points that have an intersection with the **first point** of any edges. I used the STIntersects() function in SQL and wrote down the below script :

```
select EdgeTable.id, NodeTable.idj, 
from EdgeTable inner join NodeTable
ON NodeTable.GeomJ.STIntersects(EdgeTable.StartPointG) =1
```

This code works correctly, but the problem is with their performance. As a matter of fact, EdgeTable and NodeTable have about 2 million records and the execution time of the above script is about 55 minutes which is not at all suitable for my work.

Thus, I found [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/filter-geometry-data-type) geometry function which seems a good solution for improving the performance of this task. In this regard, firstly I created the spatial index on my tables and then use this function as below:

```
select EdgeTable.id, NodeTable.idj,
from EdgeTable inner join NodeTable
ON NodeTable.GeomJ.Filter(EdgeTable.StartPointG) =1
```

But this function returns completely wrong results. For example, I tested the script for the edge 1 (idj = 1) which the start point of this edge intersects with node 1 , [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFyct.jpg) is the result of STIntersects() function and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ji4kE.jpg) for Filter. Due to description of Filter geometry function, it remarked that **this method is not deterministic and is not precise**. Hence, why the results of these two functions are different and how can I come up with it?